# Differences between exportation of png and pdf plots

Tags: r, pdf, plot, png

I have an issue with the exportation of my plots in Rstudio. The result is not the same when I export a plot in a classic image format (png, jpg...) than when I try in pdf.
Differences are not very big (different places of legend, overlaying...) but it is a bit frustrating. Any ideas to solve the problem ?

[image: pdf version]

[image: png version]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pdf` is a vector format where you specify e.g. the `width` and `height` of the exported plot in inches by default (`7`), while `png` is a raster image with `width` and `height` specified in pixels with optionally passed `res` parameter (defaults to `72`).

So try to e.g. set the same dimensions for the images and change the `width` and `height` parameter of `png` to `7*72=504` instead of `480`.